# Changing the size of a specific page in Jekyll (Al-folio)

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I've been trying to change the max-width of a specific page, but I am confused on how to do so.

I see a max_width variable in the config.yml file, but if I change that it changes the width for all the pages.

The page I want to change the width is in the gallery.md file, in which I have `layout: profiles`.
Then in profiles.html layout, I found
`{% capture sizes %}(min-width: {{site.max_width}}) {{ site.max_width | minus: 30 | times: 0.3}}px, (min-width: 576px) 30vw, 95vw"{% endcapture %}`
and I thought that if I just replaced the max_width varible with another width it'll change but it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated!